# how to put these two on the same line? (one centered, one right aligned)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two different sets of text to be on the same line.

```
<h2 style="text-align:center">Only $4 for first-class shipping on all orders!</h2><span style="text-align:right">test</span>​
```

I'm trying to have these on the same line. i thought the span tag did it, but it doesnt. when i put it in a div, it goes down a line, i need it on the same line.

http://jsfiddle.net/MWDxC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the `<h2>` centered and the `<span>` on the right - http://jsfiddle.net/MWDxC/3/

```
<header>
    <h2>Only $4 for first-class shipping on all orders!</h2>
    <span>test</span>
</header>

header {
    position: relative;
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
}

span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put display:inline on that H2 tag since it's a block element as default.

http://jsfiddle.net/MWDxC/2/

Or you could just move the entire span tag inside the H2 and that would work as well.

Comment: I don't think that is what he wants. Your span sticks to the h2

Comment: Ahh I see.  In that case, you can just put the span tag first and float it to the right.  Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MWDxC/4/

Answer (score 2):

You need a wrapping element, change the display and set a float. Then it will work.

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <h2 style="display:inline;" >Only $4 for first-class shipping on all orders!</h2>
  <span style="float:right; display:block;">test</span>
</div>
```

Comment: its because of the CMS i'm on... you're right, it does work, i found another fix though. thanks for your help. =)